# Remote query from Java code

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, json

I'm designing an Android app that stores its data in xml files locally; local data are part of all data stored at a server. I need remote file path to download and view locally. user can list remote files in a listView and check files (eg.. books) to download;

What can the structure of the remote repo be? (SQL) How can I make the query and receive result? (JSON) Any way to sync (subtract existing files from remote)?

Answer (score 0):

your question is too generic and wraps a big thing stuff, since you are asking the repository, the query mechanism and the sync between the server and your app.

the most common way to do this is allocating all you data in server database (mysql i.e. or xml files, last is too more complex) query it with a (php, jsp, asp.*) web service and retrieving the web service result (in your android application) using HttpURLConnection, URL classes to connect and read the ws result.

Later, the sync can be on a background thread that continously do the above operation.

maybe you can do it with the DownloadManager service, but i recommend you a little read to the documentation.

Comment: plz more detail on parsing result from web service??  and what is the data carrier (JSON??) ; also i may not be clear(sync means don't view items that the user already have in the cloud list)